# Javascript RegEx .match() with $1, $2, etc. selectors

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a simple RegEx match in Javascript and am having trouble figuring out the logic. Basically I have a function in the source code that I'm converting to a string. It's sort of complex but part of the function (the array part) is being generated by ASP server side code so the function is always different, depending on the user that visits the page. It's not really relevant I guess, but good to know why I'm doing and what I'm trying to accomplish. The function is this:

```
function Choose_My_Saved_Billing(arg_index) {
switch(arg_index) { 
    case 1 : {
         ChosenCopy(document.OnePageCheckoutForm, 'billing', 'Test', 'Name', '', '123 Main Dr.', 'none', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', '90046', 'USA', '3105551234', '',''); 
         document.getElementById('span_v1state_dropdown').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('span_v1state_textbox').style.display='block'; break }
    }

    if (arg_index > 0) { 
        document.getElementById('span_remove_selected_billing').style.display='block'; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById('span_remove_selected_billing').style.display='none'; 
    }
    if (typeof v65DecideCopyBillingToShipping == 'function') { 
        v65DecideCopyBillingToShipping(true);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to just get those values that are in the array after 'OnePageCheckoutForm' and put them into an array I can access with other code. The string I generate is this:

```
var function_string = Choose_My_Saved_Billing.toString();
var matches = function_string.match(/(')(.*?)(',)/g);
```

All I want is the value from the $2 variable in the matching pattern. The only way to determine the values I want are ones that are in single quotes with a trailing comma (otherwise it would match the other variable values in the function like `span_remove_selected_billing`) but I don't want the single quotes or commas in the resulting matches.

Is there a way to just getting the second parentheses in the match statement?

### EDIT

I tried this to try negative lookaheads but I guess I'm having trouble because there is no negative look behind in Javascript:

```
(')(.*?)(?=',)
```

It's close but not quite there? I think it's the first part of the statement I'm having a problem with...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What would be sample value of `function_string`

Comment: Try using `/'(.*?)',/`

Comment: An array with values like ["billing", "Test", "Name"] etc. with the rest of the values. Right now it renders like this (with the first matching pattern): ["'billing',", "'Test',"] etc.

Comment: @VLAS, that matches it like I'm doing but I just want the value of the info in the parentheses at that point...how do I get that?

Comment: Isn't `function_string` a string? How did it become an array?

Comment: try `.search` instead of `.match`

Comment: @anubhava, when you use .match() it saves the results in an array

Comment: I didn't ask output of `.match` I was asking sample value of input string `function_string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something simple like this?

```
var function_string = Choose_My_Saved_Billing.toString();
var matches = function_string.match(/document\.OnePageCheckoutForm,(.+?)\);/);

var values = matches[1].split(',').map(function (v) {
    return v.trim().slice(1, -1);
});

console.log(values); //["billing", "Test", "Name", "", "123 Main Dr.", "none", "Los Angeles", "CA", "90046", "USA", "3105551234", "", ""]
```

By the way, rather than trying to parse the function's source which is very error prone, why don't you simply generate a data structure (e.g an array) in ASP and then pass that array to the `Choose_My_Saved_Billing` function or simply use a closure. This way, you would not have to extract the data out of the function's source code.

Comment: The ASP is actually part of the Volusion framework so I don't have access to it (I should've specified that) otherwise that would be a great idea. This is sort of a workaround. This works perfect. Thanks!